# How to fire the function useEffect after clicking event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Recently am learning React hooks and am now doing a search app which have to call API then return the list movies correspond to what i type in the search box.

My code here:

useFetch.js

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export const useFetch = (url, initialState) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(initialState)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchMovies() {
            const response = await fetch(url)
            const data = await response.json()
            setData(data.Search)
            setLoading(false)
        }
        fetchMovies()
    }, [url])

    return { data, loading }
}
```

App.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Search from './components/Search'
import Result from './components/Result'
import Loading from './components/Loading'
import { useFetch } from './utils/useFetch'

export default function App() {
    const [key, setKey] = useState('Iron man')
    const onSearch = (key) => {
        setKey(key)
    }
    const {data, loading} = useFetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${key}&apikey=${API_KEY}`)

    return (
        <>
            <Search handleSearch={onSearch}/>
            <Loading isLoading={loading} />
            <Result movies={data}/>
        </>
    )
}
```

As far as i understand after clicking button search function call API will be fired and return the result as expect. I can't put

```
const {data, loading} = useFetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${key}&apikey=${API_KEY}`)
```

inside **onSearch**  function. Follow the code function call API is automatically called whenever the app start and return undefined as result.

Can anyone help me out and explain why?

Comment: Do you have any reason to use `useEffect` and `useState` inside your fetch function ?

Comment: With my little grasp of hooks I use useEffect for fetching data and useState for keeping and setting data which returns from API, so far I have referenced useFetch from alligator.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your understanding of how hooks can only be called at the top level in a react component. Make the following changes and the API won't get called the first time around but will get called subsequently.

1. Use url state variable and extract `generateUrl` logic outside the component:

```
function generateUrl(key) {
  return `https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${key}&apikey=${API_KEY}`
}

function MyComponent() {
  const [url, setUrl] = React.useState('');
  //...
}
```

2. Check for `url` presence in `useFetch` hook by wrapping `fetchMovies()` call in an if condition. This way, API won't trigger since default value of url is empty.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export const useFetch = (url, initialState) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(initialState)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchMovies() {
            const response = await fetch(url)
            const data = await response.json()
            setData(data.Search)
            setLoading(false)
        }

        if(url) {
          fetchMovies()
        }
    }, [url])

    return { data, loading }
}
```

3. Finally, modify `onSearch`

```
const onSearch = (key) => {
   setUrl(generateUrl(key))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could expose `setUrl` through something like:

```js
return { data, loading, onSearch: (key) => setUrl(generateUrl(key)) }
```